Can you downgrade a point release version (e.g. 22.04.4 to 22.04.3)?
I'm trying to use OpenCL with my AMD GPU. I was running Ubuntu 23.10 and realized I needed to downgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 to install the AMD GPU stack properly. I did a clean install on version 22.04.4 to do so. The AMD GPU stack itself can run on 22.04.4, but I figured out I neded ROCm also. The problem is, for whatever reason, it says it needs version 22.04.3. I'm on 22.04.4.

I know it's not possible to downgrade yearly (e.g. XX.04) or monthly (e.g. 22.XX) versions. Is there any way to downgrade to the 22.04.3 point release without reinstalling (again)?
I don't care if it's hacky. If it's not worth it, I guess I'll have to reinstall again.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has two primary kernel stacks... GA & HWE (plus OEM options I'm ignoring here)..   Whilst 22.04 using the GA kernel stack alters, the HWE kernel stack will change during the life of the product. The release never changes (22.04), but the point of applying security fixes does upgrade (.1, .2, .. .5) so you want to run a system without applying all security fixes???  You're looking at the wrong thing; you maybe should consider changing kernel stack  (22.04.4 uses the 5.15 or 6.5 depending on kernel stack defaults of install media!)

FYI:  You can uncleanly or non-destructively re-install some Ubuntu Desktop systems (inc. flavors) thus achieving a backwards release change (from 23.10 to 22.04 for example) .. and I've written an answer on that here  (though there are risks going backwards as I touch on).   Releases in August (2024) are 24.04.1 & 22.04.5; and I'll likely include systems on 24.04.1 (first actual release) reverting to that earlier release (22.04.5); as thats the order of release & I use an existing QA test system (with data on it) in QA. but that's via re-install rather than package downgrade..

@guiverc I forgot that thread and forgot it was what I needed. I was looking for my solution and never found that thread again. Thank you, that is what I need. You know what I mean when I need to downgrade. I don’t want less security patches. It’s the kernel version I need

@guiverc Do you think I need an older HWE stack? I suppose I should research more about how the HWE stack works with its updates and all. I still don’t quite understand even after reading the answer from that thread

Ubuntu HWE kernels come from the later releases; 22.04 moved from the GA kernel of 5.15 to the 5.19 from 22.10, then to 6.2 from 23.04, is now on 6.5 from 23.10, and will move to 6.8 from 24.04 LTS. I'd not suggest using an older unsupported kernel from a release that is EOL (ie. 5.19 from 22.10, 6.2 from 23.04 etc), as there are reasons (security!) why the kernel upgrades when it does.. Your safe option is to use a different stack (eg. GA, or an OEM stack if suitable for your hardware; ie. offered at install if you used an ISO that offers it).

To learn more about HWE I suggest reading https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  (from memory it includes links to the other useful pages too)    FYI:  If your system is offline, you can use whatever kernel you like, as the lack of security of using a kernel no longer supported (ie. from an EOL release thus unpatched for security flaws by Ubuntu) is moot anyway.

I will read that and consider changing to the GA kernel stack. Thank you @guiverc
